# Oracle Apex login screen error

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

As per oracle apex installation steps have installed apex 4.2 in oracle 11g environment. After starting the liseneter(ords) still could not able to view the oracle apex login page.

Getting the following error :
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Tue, 15 Apr 2014 02:40:27 UTC

Message: 'apex' is undefined
Line: 35
Char: 1
Code: 0

Message: 'apex' is undefined
Line: 110
Char: 1
Code: 0

Can someone please help? Note : Have also ran the apxldimg.sql as well.

Comment: What URL are you using to access apex, and what port is it listening on?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/ords.

Comment: And it is listening on 8080.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while starting the listener we need to poin the images since i did not do that it caused issue while loading the page.

java -jar ords.war standalone  --port 8586 --apex-images F:\app\apex_4_install\apex_4.2.5_en\apex\images

Comment: Hello there. I am trying with "/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -jar ords.war standalone --apex-images /media/hdd/apex/i_devdb11 --context-path /ords --static-context-path /i_devdb11" and I did not manage to get the images. Am I missing something?